# iPython Notebook; Plotting transition diagrams

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook, diagram, markov-chains

My question is dead simple.

Is there a package to plot state-transition or markov diagrams that look like any of the following? I am thinking it has to exist, but I simply can't find it!

[image]
[image]

I've really had a search around, also on Stackoverflow, but to no avail.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you install graphviz and pygraphviz as mentioned above, you can render dot syntax directly in a ipython/jupyter notebook like this (without the need for networkx):

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
from IPython.display import Image

def draw(dot):
    return Image(pgv.AGraph(dot).draw(format='png', prog='dot'))

g1 = """digraph top {
   a -> b -> c;
}"""
draw(g1)
```

This draws:

[image]

Complete dot reference [here](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/dotguide.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Right. I found the following packages, installed in the *correct* order, will produce the graphs I was looking for.

1) Install Graphviz. This is a standalone package, and can be installed with e.g. brew install graphviz.

2) Install PyGraphviz using pip install pygraphviz (requires Graphviz executables)

3) Install PyDot using pip install pydot

If you want to do inline stuff in iPython Notebook, as I do, then check out [this](https://github.com/chebee7i/nxpd)

Comment: The Jupyter Notebook setup is almost like this, but I cannot get it working:  
`sudo apt-get install graphviz libgraphviz-dev graphviz-dev pkg-config`
`pip install pygraphviz`